# React Native - Fetch JSON returns different URL

Tags: react-native

So I'm way out of my league here trying to get this React Native application speaking with a Django Rest API. I can successfully get a response from a view, but I am unable to POST to the database (other side of Django)

Here is my bit of code that i'm having problems with...

```
  postRequest() {
    const token = "username:password";
    const hash = Base64.encode(token);
    const Basic = "Basic " + hash;

    fetch("https://AZUREWEBSITEADDRESSOMMITTEDFOROBVIOUSREASONS/resident/add/", {
        credentials: "same-origin" }, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: Basic
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          facility: "1",
          first_name: "Test",
          last_name: "FromApp",
          dob: "1986-09-28",
          gender: "F"
        })
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
        return console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

the resulting console output is as follows:

```
"type":"default",
"status":200,
"ok":true,
"headers":{"map":{"cache-control":"public, max-age=0","date":"Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:14:42 GMT",
"x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN",
"set-cookie":"csrftoken=SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN; expires=Sun, 28 Feb 2021 00:14:43 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax",
"server":"gunicorn/19.9.0",
"vary":"Cookie",
"expires":"Sun, 01 Mar 2020 00:14:43 GMT",
"content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8",
"content-length":"1835"}},
"url":"AZURE_WEBSITE_ADDRESS_OMMITTED_FOR_OBVIOUS_REASONS/login/?next=/TR_API/resident/add/",
"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":1835,"offset":0,blobId":"47fbdf14-1aa0-4bbe-af3d-6f79632cfcd7","__collector":{}}},
"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":1835,"offset":0,
"blobId":"47fbdf14-1aa0-4bbe-af3d-6f79632cfcd7","__collector":{}}}}
```

So main issue is the url returning has /login/?next=/ in it, when it shouldnt... any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to post more information. What is the expected input for the authentication? Are you certain that an additional parameter is not expected by the service? What is the format of the expected URL to be returned?

Comment: Also are you sure that they keys in your header do not require quotations?

Comment: That's where I'm in over my head, the guy who does the backend (Django) isn't responding and I really don't know much about it. I can see all the code but don't really know what I'm looking for.